# Search for value in variables in AWX

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I am trying to come up with a host filter query in awx that is able to filter for a value in a key contained in the variables field of my inventory.

My variable field looks something like this:

```
{
  "variables": "{..., \"labels\": {\"automation\": \"awx\"}, ...}"
}
```

My current host filter like this:

`https://my-awx.com/api/v2/hosts/?host_filter=variables__icontains=automation`

Using the filter above, I at least am able to receive the corresponding instance, however I'd like to be able to filter for more than `automation`. Ultimately I'd like to receive all instances whose `automation` label has the key `awx` and integrate them into a smart inventory.

One additional question: Is there better documentation available then https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/filtering.html? I feel like it is missing such details as contained in my question.

Best regards,
stiller-leser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this issue: https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/371 it doesn't look like it's supported yet.

One suggested workaround:

> You can build your inventory, using a dynamic script or otherwise, and
>   then create a playbook that caches the desired host variables as
>   ansible facts.